# How to modify request input after validation in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I found method [Request::replace](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_replace), that allows to replace input parameters in Request.

But currently i can see only one way to implement it - to write same replacing input code in every controller action.

Is it possible somehow to group code, that will be executed after request successful validation, but before controller action is started?

For example, i need to support ISO2 languages in my api, but under the hood, i have to transform them into legacy ones, that are really stored in the database. Currently i have this code in controller:

```
// Controller action context
$iso = $request->input('language');
$legacy = Language::iso2ToLegacy($iso);
$request->replace(['language' => $legacy]);

// Controller action code starts
```

Comment: [Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware)?

Comment: I don't think middleware works after validation.. validation is most often done AFTER middleware.

Comment: Can you expand what you're asking and then I will come back and see if I can answer in a few hours? **Why do you need this? What is the end goal? Examples?**

Comment: @CayceK yes, i thought about middleware too, but it should work before validation starts.. added example to the question.

Comment: @CayceK perhaps it is possible somehow to do with events? E.g. fire event after request validation is passed?

Comment: I didn' think you could use middle ware like the below answer. See if that works for you. i would be very interested to know if it does. But middleware is starting to look more correct.

Comment: Simple example: the user types a currency in his locale format (US: 1,234.56 | DE: 1.234,56). After validation, I need this amount as a double (1234.56)

Answer (score 11):

I think what you're looking for is the `passedValidation()` method from the `ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait` trait

How to use it:

1. Create custom Request: `php artisan make:request UpdateLanguageRequest`
2. Put validation rules into the `rules()` method inside `UpdateLanguageRequest` class
3. Use `passedValidation()` method to make any actions on the Request object after successful validation

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\...\Language;

class UpdateLanguageRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // here goes your rules, f.e.:
            'language' => ['max:255']
        ];
    }


    protected function passedValidation()
    {
        $this->replace(['language' => Language::iso2ToLegacy($this->language)]);
    }
}
```

4. Use `UpdateLanguageRequest` class in your Controller instead `Request`

```
public function someControllerMethod(UpdateLanguageRequest $request){
    // the $request->language data was already modified at this point
}
```

*And maybe you want to use `merge` not `replace` method since replace will replace all other data in request and the `merge` method will replace only specific values

Comment: tried this, I am applying a Hash to a password input. `dd` inside Request class shows password hashed, but inside the controller `$request->validated()` is showing plain password. '(

Comment: works if I put my logic in `prepareForValidation` instead of `passedValidation`. But I want to modify the input after validations and not before '(

Comment: Finally working. when we use `validated()` in our controller we get the data from the `validator`, not the `request`. According to laravel best practices it's the way to pass validated data to our model: `$user->update($request->validated());` in order to keep skinny controllers whenever is possible. The solution is overwrite the `validated` method in our request class besides the replacement in the `passedValidation`. This is what i did `return array_merge(parent::validated(), ['password' => $this->input('password')]);` Your post helped me to find the way.

Answer (score 4):

This solution worked for me based on Alexander Ivashchenko answer above:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\User;

class UserUpdateRequest extends UserRequest
{

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name'=>'required|string',
            'email'=>'required|string|email',
            'password'=>'min:8'
        ];
    }
}
```

Our parent `UserRequest` class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\User;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

abstract class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Handle a passed validation attempt.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function passedValidation()
    {
        if ($this->has('password')) {
            $this->merge(
                ['password' => Hash::make($this->input('password'))]
            );
        }
    }

    public function validated(): array
    {
        if ($this->has('password')) {
            return array_merge(parent::validated(), ['password' => $this->input('password')]);
        }
        return parent::validated();
    }
}
```

I am overriding validated method also. If we access each input element individually his answer works but in order to use bulk assignment in our controllers as follow we need the `validated` overriding.

```php
...
public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request, User $user): JsonResource
{
    $user->update($request->validated());
    ...
}
...
```

This happens because `validated` method get the data directly from the Validator instead of the Request. Another possible solution could be a custom validator wit a DTO approach, but for simple stuff this above it's enough.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible somehow to group code, that will be executed after
>   request successful validation, but before controller action is
>   started?

You may do it using a middleware as validator, for example:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

class InputValidator
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $fullyQualifiedNameOfModel)
    {
        $model = app($fullyQualifiedNameOfModel);

        $validator = app('validator')->make($request->input(), $model->rules($request));

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            return $this->response($request, $validator->errors());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function response($request, $errors)
    {
        if($request->ajax()) {
            return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput();
    }
}
```

Add the following entry in the end of `$routeMiddleware` in `App\Http\Kernel.php` class:

```
'validator' => 'App\Http\Middleware\InputValidator'
```

Add the `rules` method in `Eloquent Model` for example, `app\Product.php` is model and the `rules` method is declared as given below:

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|unique:products,title,'.$request->route()->parameter('id'),
        'slug' => 'required|unique:products,slug,'.$request->route()->parameter('id'),
    ];
}
```

Declare the route like this:

```
$router->get('create', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@create',
    'as' => 'Product.create',
    'permission' => 'manage_tag',
    'middleware' => 'validator:App\Product' // Fully qualified model name
]);
```

You may add more `middleware` using array for example:

```
'middleware' => ['auth', 'validator:App\Product']
```

This is a way to replace the `FormRequest` using a single `middleware`. I use this `middleware` with `model name` as argument to validate all my models using a single `middleware` instead of individual `FormRequest` class for each controller.

Here, `validator` is the `middleware` and `App\Product` is the model name which I pass as argument and from within the `middleware` I validate that model.

According to your question, the code inside your controller will be executed only after input validation passes, otherwise the `redirect/ajax response` will be done. For your specific reason, you may create a specific `middleware`. This is just an idea that could be used in your case IMO, I mean you can add code for replacing inputs in the specific `middleware` after validation passes.

Answer (score 0):

Use merge instead of replace

```
$iso = $request->merge('language');
$legacy = Language::iso2ToLegacy($iso);
$request->merge(['language' => $legacy]);
```